# Problem with ajax and posting non-latin characters

Tags: mysql, utf-8, translation

Posting non-latin based languages with ajax + jquery doesn't save to mysql the correct text.

**What I have done is this:**

- I am getting multiple translated words from Google's translation api.
- The *ajax request is showing the correct translations* for all languages.
- But when i try and insert this into the db it shows up in php my admin as garbled text
- I added AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 to .htaccess file on the root.
- I tried setting the header in php to utf-8 and this did not work.
- I have tried adding a contentType to ajax setup but this didn't work also.

I am  using the following jquery code:

I am able to see the translated text sent to the save_translation.php page

```
 var d = {"english":"<?php echo $w;?>","addwords":translated};
   data = jQuery.param(d);
   $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     data:data,
     url:"save_translation.php"
     });
```

Each field is set to utf8_general_ci

### **UPDATED : responses:**

**Ajax post**

> english:thank you addwords:baie
>   dankie|falemnderit|شكرا|дзякуй|благодаря|gràcies|谢谢|谢谢|謝謝|hvala
>   vam|děkuji|tak|dank u|thank you|tänan
>   teid|salamat|kiitos|merci|grazas|Danke|σας
>   ευχαριστώ|תודה|धन्यवाद|köszönöm|þakka þér|terima kasih|go raibh maith
>   agat|grazie|ありがとう|감사합니다|paldies|ačiū|Ви благодарам|terima
>   kasih|nirringrazzjak|takk skal du ha|تشکر از
>   شما|dziękuję|obrigado|mulţumesc|спасибо|хвала|ďakujem|hvala|gracias|asante|tack|salamat|คุณขอบคุณ|teşekkür
>   ederim|спасибі|cảm ơn bạn|ddiolch 'ch|אַ דאַנק

**Server Side ouput**

> english : thank you
>  baie
>   dankie|falemnderit|شكرا|дзякуй|благодаря|gràcies|谢谢|谢谢|謝謝|hvala
>   vam|děkuji|tak|dank u|thank you|tänan
>   teid|salamat|kiitos|merci|grazas|Danke|σας
>   ευχαριστώ|תודה|धन्यवाद|köszönöm|þakka þér|terima kasih|go raibh maith
>   agat|grazie|ありがとう|감사합니다|paldies|ačiū|Ви благодарам|terima
>   kasih|nirringrazzjak|takk skal du ha|تشکر از
>   شما|dziękuję|obrigado|mulţumesc|спасибо|хвала|ďakujem|hvala|gracias|asante|tack|salamat|คุณขอบคุณ|teşekkür
>   ederim|спасибі|cảm ơn bạn|ddiolch 'ch|אַ דאַנק|

Each field is set to utf8_general_ci

**PhpMyAdmin**

> thank you|baie
>   dankie|falemnderit|Ø´ÙƒØ±Ø§|Ð´Ð·ÑÐºÑƒÐ¹|Ð±Ð»Ð°Ð³Ð¾Ð´Ð°Ñ€Ñ|grÃ
>   cies|è°¢è°¢|è°¢è°¢|è¬è¬|hvala vam|dÄ›kuji|tak|dank u|thank you|tÃ¤nan
>   teid|salamat|kiitos|merci|grazas|Danke|ÏƒÎ±Ï‚
>   ÎµÏ…Ï‡Î±ÏÎ¹ÏƒÏ„ÏŽ|×ª×•×“×”|à¤§à¤¨à¥à¤¯à¤µà¤¾à¤¦|kÃ¶szÃ¶nÃ¶m|Ã¾akka
>   Ã¾Ã©r|terima kasih|go raibh maith
>   agat|grazie|ã‚ã‚ŠãŒã¨ã†|ê°ì‚¬í•©ë‹ˆë‹¤|paldies|aÄiÅ«|Ð’Ð¸
>   Ð±Ð»Ð°Ð³Ð¾Ð´Ð°Ñ€Ð°Ð¼|terima kasih|nirringrazzjak|takk skal du
>   ha|ØªØ´Ú©Ø± Ø§Ø²
>   Ø´Ù…Ø§|dziÄ™kujÄ™|obrigado|mulÅ£umesc|ÑÐ¿Ð°ÑÐ¸Ð±Ð¾|Ñ…Ð²Ð°Ð»Ð°|Äakujem|hvala|gracias|asante|tack|salamat|à¸„à¸¸à¸“à¸‚à¸
>   à¸šà¸„à¸¸à¸“|teÅŸekkÃ¼r ederim|ÑÐ¿Ð°ÑÐ¸Ð±Ñ–|cáº£m Æ¡n báº¡n|ddiolch
>   'ch|×Ö· ×“×Ö·× ×§

Comment: I recommend you add ajax and jquery tags in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it will be enough to use JavaScript function `encodeURIComponent`.

If you don't add parameters manual to the URL like `myUrl + '?param1=' + param1 + '&param2' + param2`, but use construction `myUrl + '?' + jQuery.param({param1:param1, param2:param2})` then encoding with respect of the function function `encodeURIComponent` will make jQuery for you. In the case all '&' characters and 'paramX=' strings will be also added for you.

But the best way to use `data` parameter of the `jQuery.ajax` method. If you use

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: myUrl,
    data: {param1:param1, param2:param2},
    //...
});
```

then your URL will be appended with `'?param1=' + param1 + '&param2' + param2` with the corresponding encoding full from `jQuery`.

If my tips not helps you, please post your code example.

**UPDATED**: After you posted test data it was clear, that you have no problem with `ajax` request. You show that the data of the server look like absolutely correct. So your problem is somewhere between PHP and MYSQL. I works with no from this two products and can now not really help you. Probably information from the following link could help you [string issue of utf-8 encoding with PHP and MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370915/string-issue-of-utf-8-encoding-with-php-and-mysql). You can try also

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

I wish you much success and quick solving of your problem.
Regards

P.S. In your `ajax` request you can directly use `data: {"english":"<?php echo $w;?>","addwords":translated}`. The call jQuery.param will make jQquery for you because the type of `data` is not a string. But it's absolutely independ on your problems.

Comment: Thanks a million! Using the two SQL statements got it working!  Which i should have tried a few days ago because i already had to use set charset utf8 before selecting a language 

- jason